# How to answer questions about whether you are taking on new doctoral students when admission is determined by a committee and a competitive process?

Tags: graduate-admissions

Because I teach at a doctoral institution, I get plenty of e-mails from prospective students asking me if I'm taking new doctoral students in the next academic year.

I'm not always sure how to answer them. Because admissions are done as a committee of the whole, I might have a student, I might not. It depends on my colleagues and on the applicant pool. I also don't want to encourage or dissuade prospective students too much either.

Do you have a phrase or response which encapsulates this complexity?

Comment: I have never been in this situation so I will not venture an answer, but here is my thought: "There may be space in my lab [group] next year.  Also, I want to make sure you know about these other members of the department with related research interests to mine that you might want to take a look at (provide links).  I'm sorry I don't have a more precise answer for you at this time.  [name of month] would be a good time to ask again, if you are still interested."

Comment: Speaking from a student perspective, I remember emailing and asking this question because *applications are freaking expensive*. I didn't have a ton of money to spend, so I wanted to be strategic; if the professors whose research most intrigued me weren't interested in taking on new students, period, then I wasn't going to waste my limited funds on applying to that school.

Comment: Ah, so you want to be told no. That's a useful data point, thanks Tony.

Comment: Sometimes, even with the competitive selection, students are actually asked to contact potential advisors and then in the committee advisors are asked if there are students they would like to take. With this in mind, you could at least tell them if their interests match (or if there is no chance) or what you would say if it was your decision. Of course still tell them the actual selection process is not in your hands.

Comment: Does the admission process in your university require to find a potential advisor before applying?

Comment: @RoboKaren I wouldn't take that as students wanting to hear *no*. I feel that your comment was a bit snarky. In any case, you would be surprised by the number of students who actually don't have the money to apply to many schools. Is it fair of us to ask whether or not it would be a waste of money to apply? Yes, yes it is.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice -  I didn't mean to sound snarky. I was serious. Even if I know a student doesn't have a serious chance, I don't want to be discouraging - especially when I don't know them well. I've been worrying about hurting their feelings, but knowing that finances are a concern helps mitigate that concern.

Comment: @RoboKaren I get that, but it sounded like you were discriminating students based on their financial situation, using it as a sort of excuse to dismiss them. "*Oh, you're a decent applicant but if you're concerned about money don't bother because you have only a slight chance of being accepted*"; that's kinda what I heard, but I get that that wasn't your intention :)

Comment: @ChrisCirefice - Faculty have no way of telling if a grad prospie is a trust-fund-baby or is on Medical. We don't get their financial aid documents - in all the programs I've been on, we've been need-blind.

Comment: @RoboKaren Ah, that makes sense. Changes thins a little bit doesn't it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You give one of the two possible answers:

- No, I am not taking on doctoral students.
- Yes, I am interested in taking on doctoral students but who actually gets a place is decided by the admissions committee, not by me.

Comment: +1: As per [tonsydg's comment](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/78876/how-to-answer-questions-about-whether-you-are-taking-on-new-doctoral-students-wh#comment193699_78876), I think this would have been the most useful set of answers for me.

Comment: Agreed - I think there's an important distinction to draw between the *professor* taking graduate students and the *department* taking graduate students. In departments I've experienced, it's definitely been a two-stage process. First you get accepted to the graduate program, and then (after rotations) you get accepted to a particular lab/adviser. So there's certainly a place to say "I am taking students, but you'll have to get accepted by the department first."

Answer (score 17):

I explain that admissions decisions are made by committee and encourage the student to apply.  No matter how strong or weak the prospective student is, the decision is not mine to make.

Comment: As to whether or not I'll agree to advise a particular student, I'll make that decision after I've interacted with the student in person.

Comment: In my department, no PhD student is admitted without at least one faculty member declaring their willingness _in principle_ to advise the student.  That isn't a permanent advising commitment, but rather insurance against strong students being admitted and then never finding anyone to work with because their interests don't match the faculty's interests.

Answer (score 3):

I answer truthfully either "yes" or "no". Whether or not I am taking students cannot affect whether applicants are accepted, but it can affect whether or not they choose to attend my institution; so I feel it's important to be honest.